# Is there a specification for jQuery.param()'s "non-traditional" mode?

Tags: php, jquery, ruby-on-rails

[jQuery.param()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/) has two modes: "traditional" or "shallow" mode which works like HTML forms, and an unnamed non-traditional mode which encodes additional information in the form-encoded keys so that lists and maps can be unambiguously represented. This format is said to be understood by PHP and Ruby on Rails. Is there any formal documentation of what this format entails so that other systems might interoperate with it? Ideally this would be a language-neutral specification but assuming that doesn't exist I'd like to find the most canonical documentation available (even if it's in the PHP or Rails docs).

Comment: From the jQuery doc: "Because there is no universally agreed-upon specification for param strings, it is not possible to encode complex data structures using this method in a manner that works ideally across all languages supporting such input. Use JSON format as an alternative for encoding complex data instead."  Many encoding examples provided in the jQuery doc.

Comment: I agree with that, but the jQuery developers clearly thought this format was useful enough to not only support, but make the default in place of the universally-supported traditional mode. As the author of a Python web framework, I'm interested in the possibility of supporting jQuery's defaults instead of telling my users that they must always use either traditional mode or JSON.

Comment: Anything complex should immediately use JSON.  It's a well documented standard (unlike the other options discussed here).  Even the jQuery doc recommends that. Anything simple can just be single level query parameters.  I'm having a hard time understanding why anything in between (not super simple, but not super complex) should use an undocumented format.  Either simplify it to use plain name/value pairs in easy-to-understand query parameters or use JSON.  Trying to do nested objects in query parameters seems really horrible.  I'd never want to be on the receiving end of an undocumented format

Comment: There is only language/framework spec (even though not documented). More over it is against rfc3986, so do not count for any canonical refs. But I would stick with PHP version (one of the first language that support this, the most extensive cases). Since it also lacks of docs, the option is to take parse_str tests from https://github.com/php/php-src/tree/master/ext/standard/tests/strings and implement accordingly.