# Is there a spec for nested urlencoded params[]?

Tags: http, uri, url-encoding

At one point in history, server side languages started tweaking urlencoded parameters to add support for submitting data as arrays and key/value objects:

```
// key/value pairs
contact[name]=John
contact[phone]=800-555-1234

// arrays
foo[]=bar
foo[]=baz
```

I’m playing around with some edge cases in one library's nested parameter parsing, eg preservation of parameter order.  Is there a spec that formalizes how a server should process this encoding?  If not, which reference implementation introduced this syntax?

Comment: I haven't found a spec or even a name for this format, but FWIW PHP and Rails are most commonly mentioned as its origin. My own question on the subject was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904957/is-there-a-specification-for-jquery-params-non-traditional-mode

Answer (score 6):

**Square brackets in URIs**

According to [RFC-3986 "Uniform Resource Identifier (URI): Generic Syntax"](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.2.2) using unencoded square brackets in URIs isn't allowed. Therefore it's not a HTTP standard.

> A host identified by an Internet Protocol literal address, version 6 [RFC3513] or later, is distinguished by enclosing the IP literal within square brackets ("[" and "]").  This is the only place where square bracket characters are allowed in the URI syntax.

Many programming languages are using square brackets for arrays, therefore I guess it was a natural carry-over to use square brackets in URIs.

> Is there a spec that formalizes how a server should process this encoding?

No, at least not language independent.

**First Implementation**

A lot of web application frameworks allow reuse of the same key in the query to create an array, for example `http://example.org/?foobar=hello&foobar=world`. These frameworks also allow to use square brackets in keys, but it makes no difference, they are just part of the name. Associative arrays are rarely supported. (Caveat: I'm not familiar with all this languages.)

- Perl, 1987: Numbered Arrays are supported, but not associative arrays.
- PHP, 1995: Supports numbered arrays as well as associative arrays.
- Active Server Pages (ASP), 1996: Numbered Arrays are supported, but not associative arrays.
- JavaServerPages (JSP), 1999: Numbered Arrays are supported, but not associative arrays.
- JAX-RS (Java), 2008: Numbered Arrays are supported, but not associative arrays.

So far PHP is the only language I've found, which supports associative arrays in URLs without custom code.

Comment: I know that programming languages have long used them in their syntax, but I'm interested in their usage in URI query strings. I need a spec/reference implementation I can analyze the behavior of.

Comment: @BradKoch: Sorry, I only wrote down half of my thoughts. I don't think we can provide you a language independent answers. What kind of server are you working with?

Comment: I'm doing some tests against a Clojure library.  That's irrelevant though, I'm trying to find the original reference implementation so that I can see how it behaves.

Comment: @BradKoch By original reference implementation you mean the first server which implemented square bracket syntax? No matter which kind of language it's implemented in?

Comment: Yes, the first implementation which the other languages copied.

Comment: At least jQuery encodes its square brackets, so the actual parameters are `foo%5B%5D=`, not `foo[]=` (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.param/)

Comment: Thanks, the exhaustive list is useful, more behaviors to compare. Were you able to get a sense of whether one was earlier than the others?

Comment: Awarding you the bounty, well deserved for the thorough work you've put into this.  I think we can still get a bit more definitive, I want to do a bit more digging myself too.

Comment: @BradKoch: Thanks for the award. Unfortunately, I didn't found any other framework which supports associative arrays like PHP without custom code.

Answer (score 1):

`http_build_query` has been in PHP for a very long time.  Probably that.  https://php.net/http_build_query