# How to put an array into a URLQueryItem?

Tags: arrays, swift, url, urlcomponents

I'm using Firebase dynamic links and need to put an array of strings into the value of a URLQueryItem and then be able to convert it back into an array when the link is received. How can I do this?

I tried

```
let queryItem = URLQueryItem(name: "array", value: ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"])
```

but this resolves to the error: "Cannot convert value of type '[String]?' to expected argument type 'String?'".

When I'm handling opening this URLQueryItem, how do I handle an array? I'll be able to extract the value of the query item in the below way, but how can I convert that back to an array of strings?

```
let components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)
let queryItems = components.queryItems
for queryItem in queryItems {
    if queryItem.name == "array" {
        let unwrappedStringifiedArray = queryItem.value ?? []
        //what do I do with the unwrapped stringified array here?
    }
}
```

Comment: Make one queryItem for each string. Then add them all as an array to your urlComponents.

Answer (score 0):

The way I would build a URL with an array of values would be:

```swift
func buildURL() -> URL? {
    let url = URL(string: "https://...")!
    var components = URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)!

    let values = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3"]
    components.queryItems = values.map { URLQueryItem(name: "array[]", value: $0) }

    return components.url
}
```

And the way I would parse a URL would be

```swift
func parse(url: URL) -> [String]? {
    URLComponents(url: url, resolvingAgainstBaseURL: false)?
        .queryItems?
        .filter { $0.name == "array[]" }
        .compactMap { $0.value }
}
```

Now, whether you use the `key[]` syntax (with the `[]`), or just `key` (without the `[]`) is up to you. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/30400578/1271826. But the idea is the same, either way, that you repeat the key name in the URL for each value in the array, rather than `key=[value1,value2]` or anything like that.

Answer (score 0):

```
let dictionary: [String: Any] = { 
    "array": ["value0", "value1"]
}
```

if you need your array key `https://baseurl.com?array[0]=value0&array[1]=value1`
the func would be like this

```
func queryItems(dictionary: [String: Any]) -> [URLQueryItem] {
    let dictlist = dictionary.map { $0 }
    var queryList: [URLQueryItem] = []
    
    for dict in dictlist {
        if let array = dict.value as? [String] {
            for index in 0...array.count - 1 {
                queryList.append(URLQueryItem(name: "\(dict.key)[\(index)]", value: array[index].replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")))
            }
        } else {
            queryList.append(URLQueryItem(name: dict.key, value: (dict.value as? LosslessStringConvertible)?.description))
        }
    }
    return queryList
}
```

if you need the array key `https://baseurl.com?array[]=value0&array[]=value1` you can delete `index` on the function. it would be like this

```
func queryItems(dictionary: [String: Any]) -> [URLQueryItem] {
    let dictlist = dictionary.map { $0 }
    var queryList: [URLQueryItem] = []
    
    for dict in dictlist {
        if let array = dict.value as? [String] {
            for index in 0...array.count - 1 {
                queryList.append(URLQueryItem(name: "\(dict.key)[]", value: array[index].replacingOccurrences(of: " ", with: "%20")))
            }
        } else {
            queryList.append(URLQueryItem(name: dict.key, value: (dict.value as? LosslessStringConvertible)?.description))
        }
    }
    return queryList
}
```